# How do i get the last modified date of image files stored in assets folder?

Tags: android

```
private void getFileDate(String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    Date dt = new Date(); 
    dt.setTime(file.lastModified());

    Toast.makeText(this, file.lastModified()+"_"+file.getAbsolutePath().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

When i call

> getFileDate("images/ironman.jpg");

The time in milis is always shown as 0. Is it possible to get last created date from images stored in the assets folder? if so then how?

**Please note** that the file does exist in the assets folder within a subfolder named images. Also i am able to load it into an ImageView but not able to get the last modified date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as last modified date for files in assets.
There also is no creation date.
The only thing you can determine is file size.
The assets is not a file system but a resource.
The File class can not be used for it too.

Files in assets can not be modified either.

Comment: is it possible to get the lastModifiedDate after i copy those images to the sdcard? and then retrieve those same images from the sdcard itself?

Comment: No. As a last modified date is not contained in the file it self but separately saved on file system. If you copy the file to external memory or sd card then you will get a date. But that will be the datetime of when you copied the file.